# Opening new tab with url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a function to open a new tab with `item.url`.
The problem is, the `item.url` property is given by client, not by me.
So I cannot ensure if it starts with `https://` or `http://`.
For example, user can give `google.com` instead of `https://google.com`.

Below is my code. (This component is on `/example`)

```
<URLText onClick={() => window.open(item.url, '_blank')}>Click</URLText>
```

- `URLText` is just a styled component(div).
- If `item.url` is `google.com`, it opens a new tab with url `localhost:3000/example/google.com`,
  instead of opening just `google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
<URLText onClick={() => window.open('//'+item.url, '_blank')}>Click</URLText>
```

Sample fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pecu0szq/12/

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```js
<URLText onClick={() => window.open((item.url.startsWith("http://") || item.url.startsWith("https://")) ? item.url : "http://" + item.url, '_blank')}>Click</URLText>
```

This uses the ternary operator to check if the passed URL contains `https://` or `http://`, appends it to the beginning of the URL if it doesn't, and returns the appended or original value to the function parameter.

Comment: Is it OK to assume that any website using `https://` will redirect HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: No, it's not safe and I'm not sure. I'd recommend using Zam Abdul Vahid's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.protocol`  to get the protocol of current url.

```
function handleURL(url) {
   if (url.includes("http://") || url.includes("https://")) {
      return window.open(url, '_blank')
   }

   window.open(`${location.protocol}//${url}`, '_blank')
}

<URLText onClick={() => handleURL(item.url)}>Click</URLText>
```